# It is said that what happens in the present or future are all governed by God

Tags: belief

If it is true that all the things are governed by gods. Does that mean that we don't have previledge to become what we want to be. Or even how we live our life?

If these things are pre defined, like

- Where we are born?
- Whom we marry?
- Who we encounter in our life?
- When we die or where we die?

Or can we change our life. Can anyone provide any good information on this?

Comment: Not clear enough, are you asking [similar to this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/is-our-destiny-pre-determined-if-yes-then-why-do-our-actions-affect-our-karma)?

Comment: Similar kind of curiosity. But why not clear?

Comment: Three things are always predefined.

_Janama_ - Birth, 
_Marana_ - Death, 
_Paran_ - Marriage.

They are always governed by GOD only.... If you are unhappy with them, yes you can reject god's willing. It is your personal decision. 

What you encounter in your life is not predefined, it is on your own.

Comment: is our Destiny pre-determined? Yes absolutely! By whom? By God. But from here it gets interesting. Who is God? God is our true self, our innermost being, our reality. Therefore who is it that has predestined what? It is our Self that has determined our future of our Self. Then in that case what really is pre-destiny. Can it be changed? Yes. How? By connecting with the one who has created it (God, our inner most being, our true self). How to connect? Through the art of devotion, self-inquiry or service to all beings with spirit of discrimination and dispassion. This is Yoga :). All the best!

Comment: You mean service without the spirit of discrimination and with passion?

Comment: @mrsrizan discrimination = is this right/wrong? dispassion = spirit of detachment to results. it means that you serve but do not expect to get any fruits of the service. And I mean service WITH that spirt not without :)