# Why do we need to take another birth to pay the karma of past life?

Tags: karma

We do not remember what we did in our past lives and what we are being punished for. We don't decide where to born, who will be the parents, relatives and lot of other things? If People do really bad deeds, they should get punishment in the present life, not in the next birth. At least they will realize that they did wrong. Getting a new body & soul and paying the past karma is not the solution. If somebody has done very bad and spoiled somebody's life and if we don't see him/her getting punishment for that in the present life, the suffering persons life will be waste. Then its a Endless journey, doing bad/good karma, coming again and again in this World.

Comment: If we plant a seed it does not grow into a fully grown plant immediately and start bearing flowers and fruits.It takes a specific amount of time to bear the fruits.Similarly depending on the karma(which is the seed) it takes some time before the fruits of karma(karmaphala) are obtained.So,it may not be that all our karmas fructify within the present life span.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why efftects of karma are seen after death or in next birth?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7613/why-efftects-of-karma-are-seen-after-death-or-in-next-birth)

Comment: Good question. Imagine that you are having a very bad day today. You are feeling frustrated and you want the day to end. Finally it is time to go to sleep. You exclaim 'I am just going to forget this whole day and start fresh tomorrow'. This is similar to what happens during birth! You have chosen to forget your memories. There is no third party trying to maliciously remove your memories. Having forgotten your past, you can definitely remember it again, if you follow the suitable methods. But acutally it you might not want to remember things, so better to focus on present say the wise sages :)

Answer (score 1):

Karmic balance is associated with the soul, not body. Multiple births are a means to start afresh - you are born as a child, having no undesirable qualities like ego, greed, etc. So this is an opportunity given to your eternal self to now engage in the welfare of the society and do good Karma. Most people again fall prey to ego, lust, pride, etc and hence keep cycling in the birth/death process.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Comment: Source:- https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj04byPz__LAhWKkY4KHU56Cj8QFggeMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.quora.com%2Ftopic%2FKarma&usg=AFQjCNE96wKfaxAa8IYLeGRFDHo-uNAKbA&sig2=__T1k5KqhyeVece8RIYXTg