# Asking questions against creation and doings of God in hinduism?

Tags: gods, creation

God gave Humans brain and the ability to think. So my question is it right or wrong to question the creations and doings of God by a human?

I mean will it be considered a sin?

Please help me out, I am bit confused.

Comment: This reminds me of the Book of Job in the Bible.  My instinct is to say that it's not a sin to question those things, but I'm not sure about that.  I'd have to check Hindu scripture.

Comment: Even if you question God , answer you would get is "everything done by God is in accordance with Dharma or has some logic"( We are questioning him because of His Maya, that's power of his Maya). With time, many misinterpretations and misapprehensions  entered into Sanatana Dharma. You might be questioning them rather than God. Or you might have misunderstood "logic" behind doing of Gods.

Comment: @AnilKumar If everything that people do are acts of God because we do not understand his motives (Even a blade of grass to flutter is through the will of God, Because everything in the end is his puppet show), How should we understand and respond to social crimes that exist now?

Comment: @VarunRao i don't think  every act of human is act of god.see this http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2399/3500. Also i suggest to see @jabahar( Be Happy) answers on Karma. They are very good. Only humans have freedom to act on their own with their  residual karma restricting them sometimes. Animals and other lower species are born just to kill their karma. See this http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8848/3500 . Karma is complex topic.

Comment: I am still confused can anyone please be specific about the answer to my question?

Comment: @AnilKumar All human actions are definitely caused by Brahman; see [this section](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe38/sbe38042.htm) and [this section](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe38/sbe38043.htm) of Adi Shankaracharya's commentary on the Brahma Sutras.  (The other commentatirs agree.) Note that even though Brahman chooses your actions, he's not capricious in his he does this; he chooses your current actions based on your actions in a past birth, and he chose your actions in your previous birth based on your actions done in the birth before that, etc. going infinitely far back in time.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan But each and every action is decided by Brahman? For Eg: in next second i may think/do something. is that action too predestined by Brahman? But if that is the case we are not generating our karma on own. I don't think what we think or do in each second is predestined by Brahman.  I think our jivatma in this illusion of Brahman may do some actions on its own while some are faced/done as consequences of previous karma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a statement said by Swami Vivekananda in front of his Irish disciple Sister Nivedita [(here)](http://www.spiritualbee.com/media/the-master-as-i-saw-him-by-nivedita.pdf)

> Let none regret that 
>   they were difficult to convince! **I fought my Master for six long years**, with the result that I know every inch of the way! Every inch of the way!

Noticing word 'fought' here, which means intense questioning before accepting anything. And it is evident from Swamiji's boyhood nature as described [(here)](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda_biography/03_at_the_feet.htm)

> Inquisitive, alert, and intellectually honest, he possessed an open mind and demanded rational proof before accepting any conclusion as valid. As a loyal member of the Brahmo Samaj he was critical of image worship and the rituals of the Hindu religion.

So, it seems easy to follow that Swamiji used to ask a good number of questions about God and His doings to the Great Master (I also read it in a book that Naren(Swamiji, as called by Sri Ramakrishna) often asked questions about Sri Radha and Sri Krishna's Vrindavan Rasleela to His Master considering it unethical and Sri Ramakrishna would not deny such questions instead answered them considering emotions of Sri Radha and Her friends to meet the Supreme one. Though, I could not find it anywhere online).

And about reaction of Sri Ramakrishna to such questions, [here](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda_biography/03_at_the_feet.htm) is the answer:

> People, however, noticed the growth of an intimate relationship between the loving, patient, and forgiving teacher and his imperious and stubborn disciple. **The Master never once asked Naren to abandon reason.**

That is, Sri Ramakrishna would not deny Naren's questions.Therefore, from this great Guru-Disciple relationship, it can be concluded that questioning God and His doings is not a sin in Hinduism.