# What exactly is Karma?

Tags: karma

Till now, I just had an idea like karma is meant but the work you do. But in the comment section of the question `http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/asking-questions-against-creation-and-doings-of-god-in-hinduism` , it said karma is complex thing to understand. can anyone elaborate what exactly karma means?

Comment: whatever we do is only to have food but karma means bhakti.chanting god's name is karma.

Comment: I don't know how karma works, but first I want to know what exactly karma is..??

Comment: see answers for that question. In brief, Karma is actions you do.  There are results for your actions. You do certain actions in life whether good or bad, you will face the "effects" of those actions.  What you sow is what you reap. Good begets good and bad begets bad.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi chanting god's name has 3 aspects: 1. Just doing uchhara by mouth (shriram-shriram-shriram) 2. Just remembering god's name in mind. 3. Uchhara with rememberance.. Does all 3 aspects gives good karma to human?

Comment: @AnilKumar All it says is about the possible ways of how Karma works. But what exactly is it. Can you please provide a specific answer, I mean it should like, yes this is it. This is what karma means.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Can you elaborate how chanting God's name will be karma.