# Why do bad things happen to good people?

Tags: scripture, gods, karma, rebirth

I have seen many instances where bad things have happened to good people. And to make it worse, the bad people prospered and progressed while the good people seemed to struggle every day for their survival.

Why don't we get the results of our bad karma in this birth only? How will the results from bad karma rendered in the next birth matter at all? The good person who had to suffer in spite of being good, isn't he lucky enough to watch those, who did wrong to him (bad people), suffer in same birth?

People do one wrong after another, yet they live their whole life in luxury. Where is God in all these situations? Doesn't it seem justified that this is the reason why people lose their belief in God?

**Can you also explain when 2 people have neutral account, then how can one do wrong to other?**

Last question, just consider a hypothetical situation, where, I never did anything wrong in any birth. Are bad things still bound to occur to me?

Please point references from scriptures to enlighten me here.

Comment: This same question was asked by Yudishthira to Lomasha Maharshi in the Mahabharata. I shall search the answer and post it here.

Comment: yes, please post it here.

Comment: [Related not duplicate] [If karma works, why are so many evil or corrupted people successful](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8848/3500)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by _2 people having neutral account_.

Comment: @sv. By neutral it is meant thus- If a person V does wrong to a person J, and J also does wrong to V. And both do equally bad things to each other. Then they both are equal, and thus neutral. They are neutral because- if V does bad, she is afflicted by Paapam. But then J does bad back to V, so V's Paapam towards J, is cancelled back by J's Paapam towards V.

Comment: @Surya Give the answer.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Gosh terribly sorry I missed this answer completely.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Yes, that's what I thought too but OP needs to put all that explanation directly into the question. You can edit and add that too.

Comment: @Surya Kindly give answers.

Comment: @Sthangley ji, actually Surya ji is referring to Mahabharata Vana Parva Chapter 94. Read it if you want 

Answer (score 4):

[Original Link](http://archive.aweber.com/usr_course/FrZem/h/Wednesday_11_May_2016_Prayer.htm)

> **Question: Why Bad Things Happen
>   to Good People?**
>
> As you mentioned in the 9 May 2016 Thought for the Day, in a situation
>   where greedy, remorseless, revengeful, powerful, scheming people play
>   their dirty games and harass, abuse, insult, cause losses to and
>   disturb the gentle devotees fully aware of the situation--why does
>   this happen to the devotees when they are under the shelter of
>   Krishna? Does Krishna penalize dirty, corrupt people and protect
>   devotees? How and when? Why God delays in answering our prayers?
>
> Gurudeva, how to serve spiritual master, Tulasi devi, and Krishna for
>   their pleasure, not just to get moksha and Goloka dhama, but in pure
>   devotional service to be with them always. Kindly elaborate. Your
>   insignificant student,
>
> Rajendra
>
> **Answer: For a True Devotee Everything is Good**
>
> A devotee accepts the hell of this material world as a wonderful
>   reminder from the unlimitedly merciful Lord Sri Krishna that this
>   material world is not our actual home. Everyone is punished and
>   rewarded according to their previous pious and sinful activities. You
>   cannot change that with prayer. Prayer is for awakening the pure love
>   of God within our hearts so that we can get out of this material
>   world.  It is not for getting better facilities in this material
>   world.
>
> By purely serving the spiritual master Tulasi devi and Lord Krishna
>   are automatically pleased. Srila Prabhupada describes nicely below how
>   to serve the spiritual master:
>
> "A disciple should serve the spiritual master as a menial servant, and
>   whatever he has in his possession should be dedicated to the spiritual
>   master: pranair arthair dhiya vaca. Everyone has his life, his wealth,
>   his intelligence and his words, and all of them should be offered to
>   the Supreme Personality of Godhead through the via medium of the
>   spiritual master."
>
> Sankarshan Das Adhikari

Another [link](http://archive.aweber.com/usr_course/GqjO./h/Wednesday_10_April_2013_Don_t.htm) discussing this.

and yet another [link](http://archive.aweber.com/usr_course/KbFHn/h/Thursday_21_November.htm) explaining this.

You will need to scroll down to the daily Question Answer section on the website.

Comment: Krishna has rubber stamped this material world as "dukhalayam ashashvatam" - in other words place of temporariness and misery. (BG 8.15). Who would like to come to such a place? miserable people definitely. So even the wisest seeming person on this planet (except a bonafide spiritual master) is a miser. And that includes you and me too :). Bitter truth, eh?

Comment: ShriPrabhuPaada GuruDeva is not our Authority. Veda, Puraana, Aagama, et cetera are.

Comment: I would advise you to change your name to- **Krishna**. Because- while adding a comment to you, we have to type @ and your name. Now, your name is- **Kṛṣṇa**, which is the most correct spelling. But not many pepple would be able to do this- They would not be able to write your name as- **Kṛṣṇa** , since  **ṛṣṇ** , is not easily available in all keyboards**. Thus I advise you- change name to **Krishna**, so that while discussion users can easily mention your name.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

> Gurudev, when something good happens, we say it is Guru kripa (grace).
> Then what do we say when something bad happens? You say that having a
> Guru means one is protected, then why do bad things happen?
>
> Sri Sri
> Ravi Shankar:  Well, the divine loves everybody, however they are. If
> the happening of bad things takes your faith away, then it is no
> longer faith. But if faith stays in spite of all the bad things that
> are happening, then the end result will always be great and wonderful.
>
> Kunti, the mother of the Pandavas asked Krishna for a very peculiar
> boon. She said,
>
> ‘Lord Krishna, let bad things happen in my life.’
>
> Krishna was shocked, he said, ‘Why do you ask for this?’
>
> Kunti said,
> ‘Whenever bad things happened, I know you were with me, and helped me
> get over that, so I don’t mind. Every time I was in danger, I knew you
> were always with me.’
>
> A realisation like that is very unique. Bad
> things do not happen because you are good or not, but because you must
> have done something bad in the past; that karma is showing up now, and
> we have to face the consequences. If we had wrong food, it will show
> up as some disease. If your state of mind was very tense, then it will
> show up in your body as some disease.

From a Q&A with Sri Sri Ravi Shankar: http://www.artofliving.org/wisdom/bad-things-to-good-people

Comment: Sri Sri Ravi Shankar is not our authority. Veda, Purana, Agamas et cetera are.

Comment: Also give "scriptural" reference for thus- "Kunti, the mother of the Pandavas asked Krishna for a very peculiar boon. She said,....................."