# Verification of Dharma always triumphs at the end

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, gita, vedic

I have repeatedly heard that Dharma and truth always triumphs in the end but I have seen so many times untruthfulness win for example Socrates was killed for his rational thinking about god and everyone just went on their way to their perceptions about god . How does truthfulness always wins?

Comment: Sadhus can face any adversity with equanimity. They would not   retaliate or harm those who attack them . Sadhu dharma seems to be inherent in Socrates (who advocated  morale ,said vice is ignorance etc , in a western society that is enslaved to materialism). 
Sri Ramana Maharshi, remained poised when He was attacked by robbers. This does not mean that dharma has gone for a toss, and adharma triumphed.

Comment: ...always triumphs at the end of what? At the end of this life? At the end of this cycle? At the individual jiva's end? At the end of what? Maya is eternal.

Comment: At present or at the end of this life@SwamiVishwananda

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do bad things happen to good people?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9563/why-do-bad-things-happen-to-good-people)