# How could someone aim for moksha if his people are not protected by god?

Tags: vedas, krishna, upanishads, vedic

How could someone aim for moksha if his/her people are not protected by god? in particular if he/she is not protected? What will he even pray for? If a person wouldn't pray protection what will he/she pray for? According to the answer [Why do bad things happen to good people?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9563/23020) Arent you being irrational that for a devotee everything is good ? I think only freedom is good with some rules and regulation where everyone are protected. Why is it so hard to create such a world?