# How to get rid of Pitru Dosha?

Tags: belief, rituals, pitru

What do Hindu scriptures say about breaking out of Pitru Dosha?

What are the practical ways to get rid of Pitru Dosha?

Can chanting Gayatri Mantra 108 times per day or Vippassana meditation remove the dosha?

Comment: Rhonda, if you are a woman you must not be chanting gayatri. You are probably accruing more dosha by doing so. What makes you feel your family is suffering from pitru dosha?

Comment: @Rhonda First of all,u need to confirm that u or any of ur relatives are actually having Pitru Dosha.It can be judged from one's horoscope itself.You can also visit the following page.It has a whole lot of information about the Dosha It also mentions some simple to do remedies for the same...http://astroask.com/vedic-astrology/pitra-dosha-causes-problems-and-remedies

Comment: @Rhonda--Do Tila tharpanam at Rameswaram [Tamil Nadu]  to get rid of pitru dosha. That is the best one. Tila means Ellu which is a favourite grain for Lord Narayana.

Comment: Sorry to hear about the problems. This is what one can do make things better. At 6 am and 6 pm everyday please do namaskaram to the sun god and gayatri devi. Do this without the mantra. Just plain namaskaram. It is equivalent to the gayatri. Do not chant the om- bhu bhuva etc. please. We do not have adhikara to chant it. Chant SriRama SriRama during the rest of the day. Things will get better in due time. Just be cautious during times of asoucha.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48491/discussion-on-question-by-rhonda-how-to-get-rid-of-pitru-dosha).

Comment: Related: [Do generational curses exist in Hinduism?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15528/1049)