# What can one see of the future by realizing the Supreme?

Tags: vedas, scripture, puranas, karma

Since some events in our lives are pre-determined and some are not (from [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/is-our-destiny-predetermined-if-yes-then-why-do-our-actions-affect-our-karma)), if one gets knowledge of supreme and he's able to see the future, would he see only some things (pre-determined) that will happen in the future or everything? Also, what are some records of the sages who were able to see the past and future?

Comment: There is a difference between 1. Before self-realization and 2. After self-realization (Advaitic). In the without realization state, you can see anything specific in the future, for example, a devotee might get a vision of some good news that he is going to get soon. There are various accounts mentioned in several books about these visions. After Self-realilzation, there is no concept of future or past. Time is realized to be an illusion of the mind. Therefore for a man of self-realization, His will becomes the Future, rather than a 'prediction' of the future. All the best!

Comment: See [Did Arjuna have the ability to see the future?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11405/2995)