# Papa karma and rebirth

Tags: jiva

If person breaks legs of animals Whether he has to spend this karma in animal birth or he can spend in human birth also?

Comment: Please answer to this question

Comment: No one can say this. That fall under Aagami Karma. Prarabda Karma is karma which is destined to happen for sure and it is some amount of previous karma which is destined to take place in this birth. See this [Is our destiny predetermined? If yes, then why do our actions affect our karma?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2399/3500) question to understand Karma.

Comment: So, Aagami Karma may show it's result in this birth or next birth or may be even after 1000 births. No can say this.

Comment: @harishandroid [This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ve0j9AIQ_I) might give you some answers.

Comment: i got answer from one guruji who is discple of swami dayananda saraswati.

Comment: He told me that jiva can spend this papa karma in amimal birth and human birth also. its jiva's choice