# What is Niyati?

Tags: gods, vedic-gods, demi-god

I've been unable to find following answers regarding **Niyati**. Can anyone describe?

- What is Niyati?
- Who decides it? Is their any Deity to decide ? Or god ?
- Can it be changed?
- Or there is no Niyati at all?

Comment: Niyati means Prarabdha Karma... it is determined by ones action in previous birth...

Comment: @Texz.But it was known there would be An avatar of Lord Krishna in such kalpa in such Yuga since the beginning, how it was prarabdha karma ?

Comment: Also visit: [Is our destiny predetermined? If yes, then why do our actions affect our karma?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/is-our-destiny-predetermined-if-yes-then-why-do-our-actions-affect-our-karma)