# What is the significance of Astrology in Hinduism?

Tags: astrology

What is the significance of astrology in Hinduism? I see many famous sages don't really talk much about it, but why do Hindus give a lot of importance to it?

Comment: Jyotisha is one of the 6 Vedangas...how u concluded it's not important... 

Comment: I didn't say its not important, I'm asking how important it is? Some people heavily rely on it to predict their future instead of focusing on spirituality.

Comment: In the vedic ages, astrological calculations were imp for vedic rituals,...and these were done by godly humans!

Comment: @Thiagz Vedas though the ultimate significance is spirituality, talk about manythings with different purpose.

Comment: @Pandya Agreed with that.@Uday Krishna so can we say that it is important in calculating thitis, but not in deciding a human's destiny? Ultimately Karma decides and overrides things which has been predefined?

Comment: @Thiagz It can be said that destiny is predetermined and hence can be predicted (more precisely known) using Jyotisha. Regarding how Karma deals with predetermined destiny, visit [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2399/277)

Comment: @Pandya, thanks. The explanation was wonderful on the post

Comment: Vedanga jyotisha is NOT Astrology. Predictive astrology is a later development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Astrology is a word related to phalita jyotisha i.e predictive astrology and there are many subdivisions in that as well.

Vedanga jyotisha is not actually astrology because it deals more with positions of stars and planets in the sky. It also deals with seasons and equinoxes and so on. So Vedanga jyotisha is more related to astronomy. It was mainly used to find appropriate time for performing bi monthly, quarterly and many other special vedic yajnas.

As such astrology is not very important as per scriptural point of view.

We dont see many examples in texts like Ramayana or mahabharata where people visit astrologers to discuss their life events and to find solutions for astrologically unfavorable time frames.

However jyotisha was important for conducting ceremonies and hence muhurtam was an important aspect.

In present society it has become more popular and many other things and customs have also gained popularity.

Comment: We dont see many examples in texts like Ramayana or mahabharata where people visit astrologers to discuss their life events and to find solutions for astrologically unfavorable time frames. --- That does not mean anything. Do u find descriptions of anyone of them going to doctors even? :P

Comment: @Rickross in fact all great sages like parashara and others lived in that era. If it was so then it would be there. Regarding medicine we find in vedas itself and deities like dhanvantari and Ashwini kumaras are associated with it

Comment: You follow Tantras but unaware of the importance of predictive astrology?? Quite strange is that. All Tantra texts like Nityotsava and many others have at the beginning chapters have verses on "Dikshakala Nirnaya". Which will say if u take Diksha on this Vara/Nakshtra/Tithi/Yoga etc this and this will be the results. What is that other than predictive astrology? You are talking now like the crippled Vedantist :P

Comment: @Rickross that is more of muhurtam. If fate is already decided then whats point of free will? Whats use of anushthana?