# Does Krishna advocate the use of astrology?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, astrology

I read the Gita many years ago, and most recently [this HSE page](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28472/what-is-the-significance-of-astrology-in-hinduism). However, I was unable to find an answer.

In any text, does Krishna advocate the use of astrology in a worshipers life?

Comment: Krishna advocates surrendered principle to him and go back to him!

Comment: @AkshayKumarS - So that would be a No. :D. Right?

Comment: Yes. Literally!

Comment: @AkshayKumarS - If you post it as an answer with evidence I'll give you the check mark.

Comment: I do not know to how to paste  the reference here with html tag. One of them will come up with scripture reference.

Comment: @AkshayKumarS - Sure.

Comment: @AkshayKumarS - I've waiting a while now, and no one has posted an answer to this question. Could you post your answer, just include the link in full, I can edit it afterward if you want.

Comment: Wait. Will do it then. But to my knowledge Krishna never advocated use of astrology because his primary teaching is to live a centered life as an offering to him and go back to his abode!

Comment: @AkshayKumarS - This is what I thought, I don't think he mentioned anything about outerspace or the solar system. The only time he "sort" of mentions space was using the word *cosmic* to show that he was in control of it all.

Comment: No. Krishna does not. Your question asks for a positive proof. Logically, can't prove a negation. The Gita is a summary of the Upanishads. The Upanishads refer to the higher knowledge and the lower knowledge. It says that knowledge and study of astrology is one of the lower knowledges.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda - When you say lower knowledge, what does that mean?

Comment: This is vast topic on lower knowledge.  Lower knowledge =elementary school of spiritual. 1-6th std

Comment: @AkshayKumarS - This question has been open for a while now, and despite asking politely, I still haven't received an answer.

Comment: @user16456 The Mundaka Upanishad (I. i. 1-6) says Brahma imparts to his lineage the higher knowledge (knowledge of Brahman) and lower knowledge (inclusive of the Rig, Yajur, Sama, and Atharva Vedas - see verse 5). Higher knowledge refers to actual realization of Brahman and does not imply knowledge gained through our minds. Sankara says in his commentary on verse 5 that the Upanishads are not included in the lower knowledge as the knowledge imparted by the Upanishads is realization of Brahman.