# If everything is based on Karma, does one’s blessings have any effect on someone’s life?

Tags: karma, life

Young ones often are blessed by the parents, grand parents etc etc. the blessings are rendered useless if everything forms part of Karma?

Comment: Blessings effect to change one's life could also be part of their Karma. Karma is such vast we cant understand through our limited intellegence.

Comment: Two ways the destiny works. Universe offers you a chance, second previous Karma etc.. its bit deep!

Comment: Related or a duplicate of [Is our destiny predetermined? If yes, then why do our actions affect our karma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2399/5212)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing goes useless, every Karma gives new Karma. It is cycle that cannot be broken, But the Blessings can change result time of the Karma. It is depend on how powerful blessings against the Karma.

I am sorry I didn't find any written evidence. But you thing a deep (manthan) in it, you will get same as I told.

Answer (score 2):

Can you write a cheque for more than the balance in your account? 
Sure - but you will eventually get into trouble for writing bad cheques!

I personally feel it is the same with blessings. When giving a blessing one should be careful to limit one's expression to that which is within ones power to give. 
While it is always possible to wish someone well, it's just that your good wishes may have no impact on that person's life if your wishes are not backed by your own karma!

This is expanded on in the concepts of [Prarabdha Karma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prarabdha_karma), [Sanchita Karma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanchita_karma) and [Kriyamana Karma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriyamana_karma)

Comment: Can you please explain the last sentence which states “not backed by your own Karma”?

Comment: If you give a little thought to the concepts of free will and predestination, the amount of free will you have in any given situation is linked to your past karmas. If you've smoked all your life, you may not have the ability to run a marathon at this time. To regain that ability you would need to perform a different set of actions over time until you have the physical ability to allow you to make the choice of running a marathon.

Comment: The same applies to blessings or good wishes. Take the example of celebrities and product endorsements. A celebrity who has repeatedly endorsed carbonated sugar water would not be a great brand ambassador for a healthcare program because their credibility would then be in question....or at least should be. Similarly, if your blessings or good wishes are in conflict with what is appropriate for your situation, their net effect would be diminished until you performed the karma to change your situation to one from which you can authentically give those blessings. This is _adhikara_ or authority.

Comment: More relevant to your original question - no amount of celebrity endorsement will make carbonated water good for anyone...except maybe the sellers of carbonated water.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand now.

Comment: Claps and appreciation to the 2nd comment made by Mr. Arjun Venkatraman. Yes. I gave up vote to your answer. Expecting more good similar answers from you.

Comment: @P. Jai if this covers your question, would be great if you could mark as answered!

Answer (score 1):

One gets a blessing or boon from another,  when s/he is eligible according to their karma.  Otherwise,  one can not get a blessing/boon.  Every event follows law of karma.

Good karma gets good blessings. Evil deed gets curses.

Getting a blessing/curse is a part of karma.

It is not possible to get the fruits of a blessing, without a good deed or without eligibility. This rule applies to not only humans or daemons,  but also to angels and gods.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea behind Bhakti is that God is more powerful than Karma. Similarly our elders and Acharyas have powerful blessings. If Karma were all powerful in Vedanta then Hinduism would be no different from Jainism.

In [Srimad Bhagavatam 6 2 17](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/2/17), we find,

> Although one may neutralize the reactions of sinful life through austerity, charity, vows and other such methods, these pious activities cannot uproot the material desires in one’s heart. However, if one serves the lotus feet of the Personality of Godhead, he is immediately freed from all such contaminations.