# Will every soul become god in the end?

Tags: atma

As in the title. Also, please show scriptures or quotes from gurus to support your view. Thanks in advance for an answer.
Sorry for my english, it is my second language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Liberated souls come back](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35719/liberated-souls-come-back)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Moksha a permanent state?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2457/is-moksha-a-permanent-state)

Answer (score 1):

Every soul is potentially divine at this very moment. They will not become God, as they are part of God now(and always was). But, if you want to ask if every soul will realize that they are part of God or not, then the answer is "Yes". Sri Ramkrishna Paramhansa deb at Annapurna temple told in ecstatic mood that everyone will get food, some will in the morning, some in the noon, and some in the evening.  He indirectly meant liberation as explained by Swami Sarvapriyananda. Watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fTz6Pc4iDU

Hope that helps.

Comment: Welcome to HSE! You may refer to the help centre on how to answer questions and read [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). We insist on citing references from scriptures as you would see in the link.

Comment: It would be more useful if specific quote from Video preaching or text can be cited in the body of answer

Answer (score 0):

If by "end" you mean the ultimate end, the answer is yes. Hinduism system is cyclic. Meaning all the souls came from Bramhan and the they go back to Bramhan at the end of the cycle.
If by God you mean a state of higher being attained by good karma, then the answer is no. Soul do not become God automatically (or at some end). Good karma is necessary.

Comment: Welcome to HSE! You may refer to the help centre on how to answer questions and read [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). We insist on citing references from scriptures as you would see in the link.

Comment: "Hinduism system is cyclic. Meaning all the souls came from Bramhan and the they go back to Bramhan at the end of the cycle.". Can you please explain this part? I did not understand it.