# Is everything fixed and I (as a limited individual) am not the doer in spite of Heisenberg's uncertainty?

Tags: philosophy, bhagavad-gita, upanishads, advaita, dvaita

Is everything fixed in spite of Heisenberg's uncertainty and the so called 'doer-ship of limited individuals'?

Is there free-will or is life just a movie that we are forced to watch?

Comment: I am not talking about it repeating, I am asking about the laws of nature being fixed if there is uncertainty, there is a scope of change.

Comment: i voted to close as i found the answers to that question are enough for your question also.Thanks