# Who controls or rules my life / our lives as in all human beings ? Is it GOD or Astrological Janam Kundali or my efforts / karma?

Tags: gods, karma, astrology

While posting this, I got this [connected post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/is-our-destiny-predetermined-if-yes-then-why-do-our-actions-affect-our-karma). So I understood things related to kriyamana karma & prarabdha karma when it comes to karma, but the main question I still have in my mind is, 
1) "Who controls or rules my life / our lives as in all human beings?"
2) "Who has more control?"
3) "Is there a possibility, in any scenario we can say I am totally responsible for my own actions & Astrology & God aren't responsible for the same".

**God :**
I had various bakhti moments of many GODS. Recently (one year ago) I have experienced Supreme Goddess Kali influence on me. Feeling like Maa Kali is trying to say something or make me do something & it did turned out to be true & benefit for me & my family. It felt as if SHE has been controlling my life till now & guiding me into the future.

**Astrology:**
I used to be a non-believer in Astrology but within the same period as mentioned above I also got exposed to or you can say I immersed myself into astrology to some extent & I realized our astrological planet position during our birth time dictate most of the events of our lives. I myself cross verified it with my history & important events. It turned out to be true with 90% minimum accuracy. The maximum accuracy will be known if I dive more into astrology. It also predicted my current nature & behaviour. It felt as if I was being run over a blueprint of astrological planet positions. I tested it again with mom & it was 80% accurate from what I know. It also says about my good time / rise starting from the above mentioned time & more good times coming ahead mixed with bad times. Now this time period coincide with Kali Maa Bakhti period.
This raised me the question, who’s ruling my life Maa Kali or Astrology? Both are of Hindu Mythology & can’t be denied. I have experienced both so it’s tough to conclusion.

**My Efforts / Hard Work / Karma:**
I believe in Lord Krishna’s words to do our karma. I believe in my efforts & hard work more than anything. I don’t make assumptions or don’t believe in anything quickly.  I judge, analyse & then come to conclusion. I don’t make silly request to GOD to do this ,that in exchange of some offering or so. I simply do my work perfectly & make sure the path & steps is right & then remember GOD. I remember GOD in good & bad times. Recently within the same time period I have seen my long standing effort to improve my life is slowly & slowly working for good.

Now I have experienced all 3 sections which affect my life & all seems to be true. I find it hard it choose which one is actually ruling my life / our lives as in all human beings. As believer in hard work / efforts / planner, I believe & it seems I running my life but as devotee it seems GOD as is running my / our lives & looking at astrology it seems everything was pre-planned & is still running as per it's plan. So who’s running my life?

Comment: Your karma which u have accumilated for from many births.

Comment: Astrology and Karma are one and the same, the karma answer 'why such horoscope?' Astrology does not influence life, it 'notifies' it the same way Palmisty do. The only true influence is due to 'Gochar' (moving planets) but it's so fantastic that the right dasha always occurs at the perfect age according to birth chart's primary predictions. So to conclude astrology is a 'be alert signal' which tells you what will happen but does not decide. Coming to God, it's beyond the two.