# Is it true that whatever happens to us is due to karma and karma only?

Tags: karma

Whatever *good* or *bad* happens to us is due to **our own** karma **only**, 
 Or there is a another think in play ?

Comment: Have a look at this too: [is our destiny predetermined and if yes then why do our actions affect our karma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/is-our-destiny-predetermined-if-yes-then-why-do-our-actions-affect-our-karma)

Comment: "our own karma only" -- I think for relative's karma also..for example, king gets 1/6th of praja's karma..wife shares husband's destiny.. similarly guru-shishya also..

Comment: @Archit see my question is about other than karma not not karma it self

Comment: Everything is karma or God then