Do actions of Prarabadha Karma further add to our Sanchita Karma?
I read two great answers: Is our destiny predetermined? and Basics of 3 Karmas
My understanding is that Prarabadha Karma decides our destiny and makes us takes certain actions to achieve it. My question is that is the Karma of those actions added to my Sanchita karma?
Let's just say I'm destined to have a disease for which I'll have to consume a certain prohibited food, like red meat. Now, does eating that meat cause me future karma or not?
Edit: Excerpt from the first answer states:
"But the point is, not all our actions are predefined. Only those set of actions that will give rise to predetermined events are predefined. And in our life we do both kinds of actions, predefined and not defined. Those set of actions that were not predefined are known as Kriyamana Karma (accumulating actions). It is mostly these actions that affect our karma, not the preordained ones. Generally, preordained events and actions being effects of our past life actions, once experienced, they get balanced out. But the Kriyamana karma, being newer actions that we do in this present life, get stored to be experienced later. Let me give an example for better understanding.".
Here, I'm primarily trying to figure if we can know which of our actions are preordained ones and which are newer actions as we are going through this current life.

The concept of Karma has been explained below with 3 kinds of its forms:

Sanchita Karma(सञ्चित कर्म/Accumulated) which is collection of Actions of Merits(पुण्य/Virtue) and Demerits(पाप/Vice/Evil) for all births taken until now and stored as the latent impressions (Samskāra/संस्कार) in the Causal Body(Kārana Sarīra/कारण शरीर) of Purusha(पुरुष/Self/Jivatman/जीवात्मन्). The Causal Body is the cause for the other two bodies viz., Gross body (Sthula Sarira/स्थूल शरीर) and Subtle body (Sukshma Sarira/सूक्ष्म शरीर).

Prārabdha Karma(प्रारब्ध कर्म/begun/commenced) is that portion of the past karma which is responsible for the present body, i.e. that portion of the Sanchita karma which influences human life in the present incarnation is called Prārabdha. It is ripe for reaping. It cannot be avoided or changed. It is only exhausted by being experienced. You pay your past debts. Prārabdha karma is that which has begun and is actually bearing fruit. It is a subset and selected out of the mass of the Sanchita karma.

Āgamya Karma(आगम्य कर्म/Having Arrived) which are the Samskāras gathered in this life [present incarnation] due to the Actions of Merits and Demerits. The moment this Gross body(Sthūla Sarīra/स्थूल शरीर) falls when the present life ends, this will be added to Sanchita Karma.


I) Your first question My understanding is that Prarabadha Karma decides our destiny and makes us takes certain actions to achieve it.
Answer is Yes.
A subset of Sanchita karma, which is going to sprout, will decide forthcoming birth. It may be a human birth or not! That subset is called Prārabdha karma.

Therefore, Prārabdha Karma caused your present incarnation and shapes your future course of actions!

II) Your second question My question is that is the Karma of those actions added to my Sanchita karma?
The karma you earn in the present birth is known as Āgamya Karma. At the end of your life term (when your body falls), that will be added to Sanchita karma.
III) Your third and last question Let's just say I'm destined to have a disease for which I'll have to consume a certain prohibited food, like red meat. Now, does eating that meat cause me future karma or not?

Sins committed knowingly for good cause will never yield bad karma.
Similarly sins committed unknowingly too will not cause bad karma.

You take meat in order to cure disease and this action will produce neither good karma nor bad karma. As long as your intentions are good, you need not worry!
Conclusion:
Therefore, it is the Prārabdha Karma(प्रारब्ध कर्म/begun/commenced) being responsible for existence of present incarnation and life.
Furthermore, actions committed in the present life and their consequences will be piled up as Āgamya Karma and at the end of current life-term, Āgamya Karma will be dumped into Sanchita karma.

This cycle [aka Samsāra/संसार/Cycle of Birth and Death/Cycle of Existence] continues until we reach the lotus feed of God (Moksha)!


Thanks for the details, my confusion is about differentiating the actions I'm taking because of my pre-decided Prarabadha Karma and my own-actions.
"set of actions that will give rise to predetermined events are predefined." as stated in the answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2407/48927
So how do I differentiate the pre-defined actions from my own.

The link says not all our actions are predefined. Only those set of actions that will give rise to predetermined events are predefined. What it conveys is that the choice you selected among a list choices presented before you, will result in a predefined event. It appears that you have freedom of choice and you exercise that freedom but ultimate the result will be predefined one! Answer to your question is you don't know what are those pre-defined actions. From our side, before making a choice we have to ensure that our selection should not go against Dharma. That is always safe.
