# After a plant dies, will its atma get a human birth directly?

Tags: atma, rebirth, sin

All plants are harmless and they won't be doing any sin during their plant birth.

Then what determines which birth they are going to take up in their next janma?

Comment: [Karma Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma#In_Hinduism) right now is just a theory, no one knows how it works exactly. You might get some ideas from this video: https://youtu.be/5ve0j9AIQ_I?t=121

Comment: It depends upon Sanchit Karma, [Does karma of previous life affect new life?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/does-karma-of-previous-life-affect-new-life) may help. Also visit http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/4112/277

Comment: When someone has to take a birth in a plant species of life, it's because such a soul has heavily sinful karma. That what you said *All plants are harmless and they won't be doing any sin during their plant birth* is not important at all because the sins of a soul that is born as a plant are so huge that it will not be spent just in one plant life but it will take many, many plant and animal lives to spend those sins gradually. And then after many of such lives a soul is almost cleansed of all sins and is reborn as a human with a residue of such sins.

Comment: Plants after dying may be born as another plant or insect or tree as per the laws of karma.

Answer (score 4):

**Not necessarily**.

Probably the next birth will be as another plant or as an insect or as an animal.

The Vishnu Smriti(Chapter XLIV) says:

> 1. Now after having suffered the torments inflicted in the hells, the evil-doers pass into animal bodies.
> 2. **Criminals in the highest degree enter the bodies of all plants successively.**
> 3. Mortal sinners enter the bodies of worms or insects.
> 4. Minor offenders enter the bodies of birds.
> 5. Criminals in the fourth degree enter the bodies of aquatic animals

Now,since the gravest sinners are getting born as plants,**it is highly unlikely that they will be humans in the next birth.**

**Because even those with relatively less sins are getting animal births**,it is natural to expect,that they(gravest sinners) will have to endure possibly a lot of more suffering before being born again as a human being .

**I think,they have to  pass through all the intermediate species of life, like other plants,insects and animals ,of various kinds, before attaining human birth.**

Comment: No need to post screen shot as you've already quoted it.

Comment: @Pandya Since i have not provided any online sources i gave the ss..i always do that..When online source is provided there is obviously no need for a ss..JMV..

Comment: @sv I provide a ss only when i don't give online sources..sometimes i'll be copying from personal ebooks collections..in those cases i won't be able to provide links to online sources..Only in those situations i provide the ss..In cases where i'm providing online sources in my answers there is obviously no need to provide ss then and neither do i..

Comment: @sv Ok..I thought that the onus is in fact on me to prove that i'm actually quoting from valid hindu scriptures..NOw if what u say is true then it only makes my work simpler..so thank u..But still there may be some cases where a ss will be needed.

Comment: Yeah, it makes the job a bit easy. If you see answers of BeHappy, PradipGangapodhyay, Tezz etc. they don't provide any links to their source, they just state the name of scripture, ch. & verse # & quote from it (which is good enough). Now you can request them to provide a link but if they are typing by looking at a physical copy they can't provide a link. I sometimes update their answers with a hyperlink to the source which is what you could do (instead of adding an image).

Comment: @sv. and Rickross -- I think that Vishnu Smriti is available online at sacred-texts.com website.