# Do our sins really burn away if we're reborn as animals or trees (i.e., other than human)?

Tags: karma, rebirth, sin, animals, birth

I have heard that we can not earn any merit or demerit in any birth other than the human birth.

So my question is, do our sins (demerits) burn away in animal or tree birth?

E.g., a dog born in dirty mud has to face many difficulties to survive but a dog born in a bungalow may have all the comforts and facilities to lead a happy life.

Given that, do our merits and demerits really wipe off in an animal birth?

Comment: Yes. Also, your punya (merits) burn away when you're born as devas or higher beings

Comment: Your merits are spent in human or some higher life in heaven, but your demerits (sins) are spent in the lower species of life, animal and plant birth. We don't use expression "burn away" but "spent". When you say "burn away" it means to destroy karma, and when it is destroyed you will not enjoy (merits) nor suffer (sins) of that karma because you have destroyed or burned it. There is nothing to suffer or enjoy when you have burn it away! ...

Comment: ... But if you are born to suffer your karma as a plant it means you have it, you haven't burn that karma, and we say you will spend it, gradually through several lifetimes you'll spend it. See related at http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16474/after-a-plant-dies-will-its-atma-get-a-human-birth-directly#comment41994_16474

Comment: You also said *I have heard that we can not earn any merit or demerit in any birth other than the human birth.* That is not entirely true. It is generally said that karmas are created only in a human birth here on Earth, but it is possible to create some karma even in the heaven world, although that karma is not of a great measure.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa I think OP's whole question revolves around his dog example. There seem to be happy dogs and not-so-happy ones :)

Comment: @sv. so, his dog is enjoying a "good" karma, then? :)