# According to Dvaita philosophy, is Vishnu the only God?

Tags: dvaita

As per my understanding, according to Dvaita theory the desire of every being is to attain Moksha. And the only way to attain Moksha is to attain Vaikuntha Loka. On the whole according to Dvaita philosophy there are two states of existence: one is Parmatma and another is Jeevatma. The state of Paramatma can not be attained by any Jeevatma. Paramatma is the Supreme. Paramatma is special. Paramatma is absolute God. Paramatma is Vishnu. Krishna is that Paramatma.

However it is said that Krishna (Vishnu) [prayed](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9986/12047) to Shiva. Furthermore, in the [Verse 9.23](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/9/23) of Bhagavad Gita Krishna (Vishnu) warns against praying to other demi gods.

> Those who are devotees of other gods and who worship them with faith
>   actually worship only Me, O son of Kuntī, **but they do so in a wrong
>   way**.

My questions are :

Is Vishnu the only real God?

If yes, then why did he pray as Krishna to another demi god when he himself had warned against it?

Would Dvaitins recommend praying to Shiva?

Comment: Where is dvaita involved in this case?

Comment: As per my understanding,from Advaita point of view the prayer to Shiva would turn out to be prayer to himself therefore the question will not arise.

Comment: Related [According to Bhagvad Gita, Lord Krishna is the ultimate God. So why are there other beliefs in Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18332/3500)

Comment: Dvaita is the Vedantic philosophy of Madhvacharya and his followers.  Madhvacharya thought that Vishnu is supreme, not Krishna.

Comment: ok. Then the question should  be about Vishnu.

Comment: Dvaita philosophy means philosophy propounding duality, God doesn't come in picture just by name Dvaita. There are various types of Dvaita like Dvaita propounded by Bheda Shaiva Aagamas (which hold God/Pashupati is only efficient cause), similarly Dvaita propunded by Madhavacharya (Vishnu and Jeevas are totally different and Jeevas depend upon Vishnu) etc... etc...

Comment: Shaiva Siddhanta is also a dualistic School. As per them, Lord Shiva is supreme.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Worship of one god and worship of Shri Ram](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12156/worship-of-one-god-and-worship-of-shri-ram). Krishna didn't mean himself by referring "I/Me". He meant the *Atma* or the true self. I have tried to explained in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/12189/1049), in the linked post. See if it helps.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I think the OP is referring to Dvaita Vedanta.

Comment: Yes there is only one God rest are all demi God not God.. dvaita is monist philosphy

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that you asked many questions about what Dvaita teaches. You should know that Dvaita is just one specific system of the philosophy of Vedanta promulgated by the Madhva (Madhvacarya or Anandatirtha) who was the leader of one Vaishnava tradition (sampradaya) in the 13th century. See the Wikipedia article on [Madhvacharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhvacharya).

However if you are interested in Vaishnava systems of Vedanta in general you should ask your questions like "According to Vaishnava philosophy ..."

*Is Vishnu the only real God?*

All the gods are real, but among them there is one supreme god, it's Lord Krishna.
There are no unreal gods!

*If yes, then why did he pray as Krishna to another demi god when he himself had warned against it?*

He prayed to gods such as Shiva to show an example that you can pray like that, but in the Gita He explained to Arjuna that only less intelligent people think that they should worship gods in heaven and not paramatma, Lord Krishna, instead.

> Bhagavad gita 7.23 — **Men of small intelligence** worship the demigods, and their
>   fruits are limited and temporary. Those who worship the demigods go to
>   the planets of the demigods, but My devotees ultimately reach My
>   supreme planet.

And He also said in the verse 9.23 that the devotees of other gods perform worship "in a wrong way", as you have quoted. Some people are not capable to worship paramatma, Lord Krishna, and they are not eligible to get liberation (moksha), and Lord Krishna showed an example to those people to worship some other gods. It is better to worship any god than not worship at all. That is why Lord Vishnu or Krishna sometimes worship some gods, just to show an example to people who are not capable to worship the Supreme God, Lord Krishna.

*Would Dvaitins recommend praying to Shiva?*

No, they would not recommend worship of anyone except paramatma, the Supreme Absolute, Brahman, Lord Krishna. In the Bhagavad gita Lord Krishna recommends worship of Lord Krishna only as the best and ultimate type of worship.

**Update:**
*Their Parmatma (Vishnu) prays to another Parmatma (Shiva)...There is not one Parmatma but many.*

That what you said is contrary to the teaching of Vedanta. The Upanishads say that there is only one paramatma in all the beings:

**eko devaḥ** sarva-bhūteṣu gūḍhaḥ sarva-vyāpī sarva-bhūtāntarātmā
karmādhyakṣaḥ sarva-bhūtādhivāsaḥ sākṣī cetā kevalo nirguṇaś ca

"He is the **one God**, hidden in all beings, all-pervading,
the self within all beings, watching over all works, dwelling in all beings, the witness, the perceiver, **the only one**, free from qualities." (Svetasvatara Upanishad 6.11)

If you read carefully this verse you should notice that it says there is only "one God" (eko devaḥ) and also "the only one", who is the paramatma hidden in all beings (sarva-bhūteṣu -- in all living entities; gūḍhaḥ -- hidden), and also that He is the self (paramatma) within all beings (sarva-bhūta -- all living entities or jivatmas; antah-atma -- the Supersoul, the Self, Supreme Soul, paramatma). So, there are not many paramatmas, but there is only one paramatma.

Comment: Krishna says that those who worship other demigods ultimately worship him although indirectly. But prayers to Shiva does not go through Vishnu. Shiva is independent. That is why Vishnu had to pray to Shiva.   I think Shiva is not a demi god but a God as real as Vishnu and as important as Vishnu. Therefore Vaishnava philosophy saying that only Vishnu is the Supreme (or the most important) God is wrong. Their Parmatma(Vishnu) prays to another Parmatma(Shiva)...There is not one Parmatma but many.

Comment: Ok so those devotees that pray other God do not pray To Krishna because They are not eligible for moksha means only Lord krishna can give moksha but mahamrityujna mantra in Rig Veda asks Lord Shiva for moksha and padma puran says a vaishnava is those who treat Shiva and vishnu as equal,if other gods can't give moksha so the devotees are just wasting there time so only Lord Krishna can give moksha not any other God is not true

Comment: And btw Mahabharata says It was Brahman speaking Bhagavad Gita  in form of Krishna

Comment: @DheerajVerma See above the update in my answer.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa There are 3 Gods in Hinduism: Brahma , Vishnu and Mahesh. Vishnu prays to Shiva and Shiva prays to Vishnu. How do you reconcile this fact with your claim that there is only one God?

Comment: @DheerajVerma I am not claiming that there is only one god! Where did I say that there is only one god?

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda  Padma Purana also says that  a Vaishnava is one who has ritual markings on his arms and need not worship anyone other Vishnu. There are other verses too. Shiva, Brahma are equal because Vishnu is inside them. SO, they are equal. Don't half quote.There are various interpretations to Mrityunjaya mantra. If uinterpreted properly, it also means Vishnu. So, Vishnu alone can give moksha. It is true.  Yeah. It was Brahman who speaking (Vishnu) Bhagavad Gita in the form of Krishna. So, it is Krishna himself speaking and not any other one. No doubts regarding it.

Comment: @sinister afcoruse if one is a devotee of Lord Vishnu he don't need to pray another God  even Upanishads says this and Rig veda also says that truth can be achieved by Chanting Vishnu s name.Same is with Lord Shiva if one is a devotee of Lord shiva then he need not worship other then Shiva and Lord Shiva can give moksha and I think devata of mahamrityujna mantra is Lord Shiva.Even Mahabharata says that Lord vishnu is the soul of Shiva and Lord Shiva is the soul Of vishnu,so means both are equal and those people who claim Lord Shiva is a demigod and can't give moksha is not true.

Comment: I am neither a shavite nor a vaishnavite  and I see both Gods equal and supreme even Rig veda says 'Truth is one sages call it by diffearent names

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Vishnu is the ultimate God (Paramtma) of Vaishnavas. However we find that their ultimate God prays to another God (not demi god) Shiva. Therefore there are multiple Gods. However you say that there is only One Parmatma.  "He is the one God, hidden in all beings, all-pervading, the self within all beings, watching over all works, dwelling in all beings, the witness, the perceiver, the only one, free from qualities." (Svetasvatara Upanishad 6.11)" . Shiva and Vishnu both are capable of giving Moksha. So how can we say that there is only one Parmatma?

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda It is not the same with Shiva. There is a reference that Vaishnavas (not a devotee of Vishnu simply. There's a difference) need not/ should not worhip others. I'm not aware of the quotes that Shiva devotees shouldn't worship other devatas. Mrityunjaya mantra is applicable to Vishnu(Narasimha) too. The interpretation isn't famous. Famous can't be always right. Hari Vamsha says that Vishnu is the soul and vice versa but the explanation given in that contradicts with BG and upanishads. Vishnu gives moksha .This is confirmed in various puranas.You can't say it's not true. 1/2

Comment: @Karmanya Only one supreme Brahman gives Moksha and all can't give it because moksha means reaching the abode of that Lord.There can't be multiple destinations and multiple Lords who give Moksha.The name of the that Supreme lord changes with faith."Ekam sat viprah" quote says only truth is 1 and not 2 or 3. The interpretations are different. That doesn't mean there are multiple truths.There is Chandogya upanishad quote  "Ekam Advitiyam Brahma" paramatma is only one without second. So, there can't be two supreme lords. Only the name change.I think you got my point now. Use chat to continue,

Comment: @Sinister Don't bring Puranic references (Narasimha) to  Vedas. Every Vedas Samhita mantra has Devata. Vedas should be seen in light of Vedas. Vishnu being only Antaryami of all Devas is Vaishnava interpretation. Not everyone accepts it. Also, both Shiva and Vishnu can give moksha. This is said in many Puranas and Mahamrutyunja Mantra (Veda samhita) explicitly mentions it for Rudra.

Comment: @DheerajVerma *However we find that their ultimate God prays to another God (not demi god) Shiva.* How do you know that Krishna was praying to Shiva who is **not a demigod**? As far as I know He was praying to a demigod Shiva. First we should resolve this question, and after that I will comment on the rest of what you said.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Why not post it as a question?

Comment: @sinister first of all I belive that vishnu gives moksha,nowhere I mention that he doest gives moksha but my point is that Lord Shiva also gives moksha and mahamrityujna mantra is not dedicates to Lord narasimha,because there is not even 1 hymn dedicated to narasimha avatar because narasimha avatar did t occur only when Rig veda was being wrote down by sages,and yajur veda shri Rudram anuvaka 2 uses mahamrityunjaya as a name for Shiva and in this mantra It is written the three eyed one and yajur veda also calls Lord Shiva the three eyed one so is devata is clearly Lord Shiva only

Comment: @sinister chandogya upanishad says Brahman is one without second yes it is true but let me tell you tattireya samhita of yajur veda in 1.6.8 says Rudra is one without second,so now yajur veda hymn is calling Lord Shiva clearly Brahman.Even vratya sukta of attharva Veda praises Lord Shiva you can check my question which Vedic verses depict Lord Shiva as Brahman and user tezz gave an excellent answer and svestasvatara upanishad says that knowing Lord Shiva one can get moksha and it also says Lord Shiva is vishwadhik which means one who say hiryanyagarbha being born.

Comment: Yajur Veda,Rig Veda and svestasvatara upanishad says that Lord Shiva can give moksha so means He can give moksha according to Vedic statememts and my point is that both Gods(Vishnu and shiva)are supreme and both can give moksha,I respect and pray both Gods I am a great devotee of Lord shiva and am also a very great devotee Of Lord Rama.hope  you  understand my point:)

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda These comments you are posting are off-topic for the answer and we should not discuss under an answer.  [Comments are no for extended discussion. Use chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism)