# Why do we have to wait till next life to reap what we sow?

Tags: scripture, karma, life

I wonder if there are any scriptural references or slokas that tell us why the fruits of our actions are faced by us in our next life as any jiva or as a human, and why not in this life itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Karma from previous life affect the current life?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/does-the-karma-from-the-previous-life-affects-the-current-life)

Comment: Have you heard of Sade Sati of Saturn mentioned in the horoscope? There is a reason Saturn is linked to final judgement, court and is the last planet and there is a huge fear of Shani in India for these reasons. It comes once in 30 years for 7.5 years in an individual's life, thats the the judgement period for jivas, kids might not remember their sade sati, but its usually catastrophic for corrupt people while beneficial for kind people, a metamorphosis period.

Comment: But, how is saturn the last planet @ManuKumar ? I thought that would be Neptune if not pluto

Comment: Only those planets will impact destiny and life of people on earth that can be seen from earth with naked eyes, hence there are only 7 planets of a week while 2 shadow planets/eclipses, western astrology is pure nonsense taking into account of Neptune and pluto which were discovered recently with modern telescopes.

Comment: @ManuKumar, then the last would be Uranus? Not Saturn?

Comment: Uranus cant be seen with naked eyes from earth, seven days of week ending in Saturn are seven planets of Vedic astrology. Vedic astrology is spiritual science and revealed to ancient sages and does not need material equipments to predict future, just like to know the creator God or heavenly Gods you dont need modern fuel rockets to Mars etc., nonsense, but spiritual wisdom as Self is independent of earthly matter or equipment in reality, not a slave of it. Astrology is eternal, equipment science is temporary, gravity worked perfectly even before Newton rediscovered it, but did not create it.

Comment: Thumb is finger of fire Sun, whole hand revolves around the thumb which is the local Sun, just like all planets revolve around solar sun. The middle finger in human hand is longest and is of Saturn because Saturn is farthest from Sun and finger for wearing Neelam, while last finger is of mercury and closest to Sun, finger of emerald, index finger is of Jupiter and second farthest from the Sun thumb, while ring finger contains Mars, Moon and venus which are close neighbours.Gyana Mudra of meditation is when Jupiter, index finger meets Sun, the thumb, transforming potential to wisdom of Jupiter.

Comment: What Manu Kumar is saying that one gets punished for bad Karmas during Sade Shati only, i.e. in the current life. So, it does not have to be the next life always. @juztcode

Comment: @ManuKumar , the about what you've mentioned in the comment, what is the subject that deals with this?

Comment: just the way whole system works, you can also understand it too, as understanding comes from within. Practice meditation daily in Gyana mudra, Astrology, Vedanta, Puranas, these are connected manifestations of tatva gyana, the elemental knowledge which has become the beings and entire universe. Law of Karma and reincarnation works on them.

Comment: @ManuKumar , any sort of resource recommendations for what you've mentioned in your second last comment?

Comment: Just logic and understanding of astrology, Hindus and Abrahamics are practicing customs based on a blind faith from past as they were revealed from higher sources aka God and they didnot know the logics. Now science revealed the exact map of solar system with telescopes which is in sync with human fingers and its associated planets. Abrahamic were not Hindus, but they still follow seven day week and Sabbath on last day which is parallel to Vedic seven planets. People are growing wiser now because of deep brain usage daily in modern equipments ,and hence understanding God just like science.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not necessary that the we will have to wait till the next life. But it takes time. And, mostly, the time taken is greater than one lifetime.

This can be understood if we visualize our Karmas in the form of tree that bears fruits.

Lord Shiva says the following:

> DAridrya-dukkha-rogAshcha vandhana-vyAsanAni cha |
> AtmAparAdha-vrikshasya phalAn-yetAni dehinAm ||
>
> Poverty, misery, diseases, bondage and the bad habits -- these all are
> the fruits of the tree (Atma-Aparadha Vriksha) which is the
> manifestation of the Jiva's misdeeds.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 1.54**

Now, if we visualize our performing of the Karma as sowing of seed in the soil, then it takes a lot of time for the seed to grow into a fruit-bearing tree.
And, these fruits are what we call Karmaphala.

Just like the fruits are not obtained immediately after the seed is sown, the Karmaphala is analogously not immediately experienced by the Jiva.

So, it is guaranteed that there will be a gap of time between the instance an action is performed and the instance when it's fruits are ready to be experienced.

But, it is really difficult to say how long this gap will be.

Comment: nice answer.thanks!

Comment: thanks .. and no problem :) @Sarvottammishra

Comment: It is not guaranteed that there is a gap. Whether there is no gap, a short gap, or an extended gap lies solely with the Lord.