# What do the terms "Sanchit Karma" and "Prarabdha", mean?

Tags: gods, philosophy, karma, terminology, meaning

What do the terms "Sanchit Karma" and "Prarabdha", mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the karma from the previous life affects the current life?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/does-the-karma-from-the-previous-life-affects-the-current-life)

Answer (score 1):

Sanchita literally means 'accumulated,' or 'heaped.' ([source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=sanchita&dir=au)).

So Sanchita Karma refers to a person's accumulated good and bad deeds, or their aggregated karma.

As for Prarabdha Karma, Swami Sivananda writes:

> Prarabdha is that portion of the past karma which is responsible for the present body. **That portion of the sanchita karma which influences human life in the present incarnation is called prarabdha**. It is ripe for reaping. It cannot be avoided or changed. It is only exhausted by being experienced. You pay your past debts. Prarabdha karma is that which has begun and is actually bearing fruit. It is selected out of the mass of the sanchita karma.