# Do The Hindu Scriptures Say If There Is Anything Special About Human Beings Compared To Other Unworldly Beings Such As Demi-Gods, Demons, Etc

Tags: belief

Is there anything special about human beings compared to other beings? Especially our strengths and weaknesses? Or are we just weak, or is our strengths & weaknesses determined only by our devotion or connection with God?

How do we compare ourselves to the Demi-Gods, nagas, demons, angels, divas, devas, rakashas, so on and so forth(I do not know them all).

Comment: also see [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2862/38), it's on a similar context

Comment: Yes. It is only through human life that one can realize the self or attain salvation/liberation. Demi-gods etc. do not have this luxury.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something special about humanity. Mahabharata Santi Parva section CCC says:

> The swan [Brahman] said, "..I disclose unto you a great mystery.
>   **There is no status that is superior to humanity.** Freed from sin like the Moon from the murky clouds, the man of wisdom, shining in
>   resplendence, attains to success by patiently waiting for his time. A
>   person of restrained soul, who become the object of adoration with all
>   by becoming the foremost of the supporting pillars of the universe,
>   and towards whom only agreeable words are spoken by all, attains to
>   the companionship of the deities."

Comment: Where are you getting your translation from? I tried searching "mahabharata "there is no status that is superior to humanity"" and all I got were your answers.

Comment: Read through Ganguli translation of Mahabharata here: https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b127.htm

Comment: Wonder why it did not show up in google

Answer (score 2):

I will want to clarify first of all the words you used:

**Demi-Gods :** I don't know whom you call demi-gods, but in hinduism their is nothing like a demi god. Yet demi god's definition might look similar to the Devas. The son of devas in human form are not demi-gods, they might have some *natural benefits* yet they remain humans only.

**Demons :** There are no demons in Hindu Scriptures, there are Rakshas, but they are not demons. Demon means a being having supernatural benefits for wrong deeds, but nothing can go wrong against nature(leaving nature itself), so its not possible.

**Angels :** Even their are no angels in Hinduism, some people do try to comply them equal to Hindu Devas but their meaning doesn't fits in the definition.

**Nagas :** Naga are just humans, they are not of different origin or form, they are a very close worshipers of Lord Shiva, nothing else.

**Divas :** I never heard that word in scriptures, might be you looking for Devi. And Devi is the female attribute of Deva.

**Rakshas :** Among'st Lord's creations, their were animals with mind, amongst them were , Vanar( not a complete homo sapien, generally with monkey like attributes), Rakhasa and Humans. Humans are herbivore, and Rakshas are carnivore. This is only the structural difference. Rakshas have the same benefit which humans have, but due to their carnivorous nature they end up developing qualities(Extreme Rajo + Tamo gun) in them which is the cause of evil, hence most of Rakshasas were found evil in nature ( but not all).

In short in Hindusim there are *Devas/Devis, Humans/Vanars,Rakshasas,Bhoot/Pret(Ghost) and other lower animals.*

*Among'st them the earthy minded animal ie. **Human,Vanra and Rakshasa** have a upper hand, they are give the power of **KARMA**. With their deeds they can not only challenge Devas but challenge god himself. Because of this they gain an additional benefit of gaining MOKSHA( the eternal silence, or the abode of **GOD**) for them, but others ie. Devas,Animals and Plants are restricted to assigned work and can only find **MOKSHA** while coming back to human form.*

Answer (score 0):

Only in human body, one can realise the  god and achieve Moksha. That,s why human birth is auspicious.

> **It is difficult for even the gods and the demons to achieve the human body.** Therefore after achieving the human body, one should act in a way that he has not to face the agonies of the hell. [ **Shiva Purana:Uma Samhita:Chapter 20**]

> **Garud Purana  2:49:13**

[image]

> Of all births, the status of humanity is preferable even if one has to become a Candala. Indeed, O monarch, that order of birth (viz., humanity) is the foremost, **since by becoming a human being one succeeds in rescuing one’s self by meritorious acts. [[Source](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826256.html)]**