# Is this life cycle never ending one?

Tags: scripture, moksha, death, life

Just wanted to understand if this life cycle of birth and death is a never ending one?

We know that a person/soul/jeevatama can get out of this cycle under certain conditions/circumstances by attaining moksha and **let's assume that some day every one attains moksha then will this cycle end or is this never ending cycle as something or the other will keep this cycle alive for some specific purpose?**

If it's a never ending cycle then what is it's main purpose/supreme goal? Do our scriptures have anything to say about this?

Comment: Your Q is not clear about what you want to ask. You claim two opposing things, and although you know that moksha is possible, still you claim it is "never ending cycle". Seems you are confused.

Comment: Am confused as to why is the question confusing to you? It's put simply if everyone attains moksha will this cycle end for ever or not?

Comment: some relevant info is available at this link:-https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8439/soul-rebirth-humans-and-animals

Comment: Related [What will happen when all atmans get moksha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10008/3500)

Comment: Visit [Is Moksha a permanent state?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2457/277). And [What is (if any) significance of Maya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8890/277).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this life cycle of material existence will end forever because after you attain *moksha* you don't return to this material existence ever again. 
This is confirmed in the scriptures.
Thus the [Bhagavad gita 8.21 says:](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/8/21)

> That which the Vedāntists describe as unmanifest and infallible, that
>   which is known as **the supreme destination, that place from which,
>   having attained it, one never returns** – that is **My supreme abode**.

See also [Bhagavad gita 15.4:](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/15/3-4)

> Thereafter, one must seek **that place from which, having gone, one**
>   **never returns**, and **there surrender to that Supreme Personality of
>   Godhead** from whom everything began and from whom everything has
>   extended since time immemorial.

And also [Bhagavad gita 8.15:](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/8/15)

> **After attaining Me**, the great souls, who are yogīs in devotion, **never
>   return to this temporary world**, which is full of miseries, **because
>   they have attained the highest perfection**.

See also the last verse in the Chandogya Upanishad, it's verse 8.15.1 says:

> ... concentrated all his senses on the Self, never giving pain to any
>   creature, except at the tîrthas (sacrifices, &c.), he who behaves
>   thus all his life, **reaches the world of Brahman, and does not return,**
>   **yea, he does not return**.

So, the verses say that one who reaches the supreme destination, the Lord's supreme abode (Goloka, or Vaikuntha, ie the world of Brahman), one who has attained the Lord there and thus has attained the highest perfection, and there has surrendered himself to the Lord, he never returns to this material existence again, which is temporary material existence though.

But if you do not attain *moksha*, then this life cycle of material existence, ie the cycle of repeated births and deaths (*samsara*), will not end until you get *moksha*.

Thus that expression "one never returns" means attainment of *moksha* or "liberation from the cycle of repeated births and deaths", so the life cycle is over and will never happen again. Had the text said something like "he will return to this cycle of *samsara* again" then it would mean that there is a possibility of return and continuation of this cycle. But the text doesn't say anything like that.

Comment: You can quote Smriti Prasthana 8.21 or 15.6, Shruti Prasthana (Chhandogya) 4.15.5 or Nyaya Prasthana 4.4.22.

Comment: @Pandya Yeah, I can quote some of these, but I'll quote one different verse from the Chandogya Upanishad, though. Thanks for recommendation.

Comment: Let me put this way: if there are say 1 billion humans and they all attain moksha one day (assume) then will this cycle end permanently from this world and something new starts or what would be the final outcome?

Comment: @Just_Do_It I think you misunderstood something here. That thing which is called "cycle" is not related to some particular world or planet such as this Earth. The term "cycle" is not related to some particular world, but is related to one particular individual, jiva soul (jivatma), we talk about. There is no such a thing something like "cycle of the Earth", but there is a cycle or rebirths of some particular individual soul or jivatma. For example, we can talk about the cycle of you or me as the two different individuals, ie jivatmas, it has nothing to do with this world or Earth.

Comment: @Just_Do_It Even in a case that all people on this earth get moksha, still there would be some other souls who would get their birth on this earth, and the earth wouldn't be without human population. The souls (jivatmas) from one world can get their birth on other planet or world. It is even possible that a soul in animal birth after death gets a human birth, or a soul living in heaven can fall from heaven world to get birth as a human on this earth. Many different combinations are possible. So it's not that the "cycle" is related to some souls on this earth only.

Comment: @Just_Do_It Those souls who get moksha they end the cycle of samsara because scriptures say they "never return", see my answer above, but still there are billions of other souls who don't get moksha, and for them the cycle continues on and on, of course it continues until they get moksha and stop with their rebirths.