# About Life I have 3 question

Tags: gods

1. What is the purpose of life.
2. Does God wants us to worship him.
3. Is if only for human beings that is heaven and hell is for. What about the other living beings.

Comment: All questions are answered already. See [Is the ultimate purpose of life only to serve God?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2989/3500), [Why does God allow us to suffer?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6855/3500) and [Does Karma (going from a higher life-form to a lower one) only apply to humans?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6547/3500). Search questions on this site. If you feel your questions are different from existing questions, ask one question at a time rather than many questions in one question.

Comment: 1. To attain moksha  2. No. But he guides and advises us that we are better off by worshipping him  3. Karma is only for humans.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Are you sure karma is just for humans? I always thought that karma applies to all beings.

Comment: 1. To live consciously & exuberantly while not identifying ourselves with something we are not is the purpose. <BR> 2. GOD is your real nature. Worshipping God means to worship yourself. <BR> 3. Hell & Heaven is for everyone but only human beings have a choice whether to go heaven or hell.