# What are the main differences between different subsects of shaivism?

Tags: shaivism, kashmiri-shaivism, shaiva-siddhanta

Please explain main differences between major shaivites sub-sects like
 Pashupata Shaivism, Kashmir Shaivism, Shiva Shiddhanta ,  Lingayata etc ?

Comment: Good philosophical question! Though it requires nice effort to answer.

Comment: Related [What is the difference between Raudra and Saumya sects of Shaivism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9006/5212)

Comment: your question is too broad. Please break it up into several different questions.

Comment: Limit your question to a specific topic. Focus on differences between two sects otherwise it will be too broad.

Comment: What is "etc" ? never heard of such sect.

Comment: The question is answered in first half of this book: https://www.amazon.ca/Tantra-Illuminated-Philosophy-Practice-Tradition/dp/0989761304