# Which scriptures show Siva's connection with Kashi/Varanasi?

Tags: scripture, shiva, kashi

Sadhguru Jaggi Vasudev says

> "The legend of Kashi goes by the fundamental that Shiva himself lived here. This is his winter place. He lived as an ascetic in the upper regions of the Himalayas, but when he got married to a princess, compromises had to be made. And being a graceful man, he decided he would move to the plains, as Kashi was the most fabulously built city at the time"

What are some scriptural stories connecting Siva to Kashi/Varanasi, sometimes called "Siva's city"?

EDIT:

**QUITE CLEARLY** not a duplicate of

[Why Lord Shiva likes Kashi?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10148/why-lord-shiva-likes-kashi)

or a duplicate of

[What is the story of Kasi Vishwanatha Jyotirlinga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14367/what-is-the-story-of-kasi-vishwanatha-jyotirlinga)

but I expect the question to be closed.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10148

Comment: Or duplicate of even this one: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14367/4732